# Margin when overflow-x: auto is enabled - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add some margin-right ( 1% ) when the overflow-x is enabled. You will see an example by resizing the window and look at the red border when the overflow-x is enabled... The margin to the right of the red border disappears when the x scroll is working... ?

Probably need some jquery to accomplish this.

JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/e4rEw/32/

HTML

```
<div>
<div id="test">

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th> Lorem ipsum  </th>
    <th> adhuc maiestatis </th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
    <td> dolor sit amet, meis solum eam ea, e  </td>
    <td> has ea, alii ipsum necessitatibus ex qui.   </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
table { border :3px solid red; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 98%;
        margin: 0 1%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

div { border: 1px dashed blue; 
      padding: 10px; 
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

JQUERY

```
 window.onresize = function() { 
     if ( $("div#test").outerWidth() < $("div#test").get(0).scrollWidth ) {
         console.log(" x scrollbar enabled ");
          $("div#test").css("margin-right","10%");
     } else {
         console.log(" no x scrolling :)  ");
         $("div#test").css("margin-right","0");
     }
 };
```

Comment: white-space: nowrap; is this css needed for your table? because of this the table is full width on resize

Answer (score 0):

Delete this CSS: `white-space: nowrap;` as others suggest. Because this line prevents your table from being responsive and therefore, automatically disables margin.